# Java IO user.dir Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, io

Here is my code:

```
 System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
    ///*
 Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("src/practice_code/a.txt"));
```

I need to read value from a.txt file, but it refuses to read unless I write the  path like this src/practice_code/a.txt  . Is it possible to change the default directory for IO in eclipse so when I specify the file I will only have to write a.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure a different working directory in the launch configuration(s) for your program. Select *Run > Debug Configurations...*, select your launch configuration, and switch to the *Arguments* tab. You'll find the entry for the working directory at the tab's bottom.